# why my program does not work. i need a program that check file for creation date and download only new one

Tags: powershell

**why my program does not work. i need a program that check file for creation date and download only new one?**

```
$url = "http://www.automo.com/prices.php?uid=0d85f09deeabc9f7473512ee368ed321&opt=Acura&type=csv"
$output = "c:\download\price.csv"
$start_time = Get-Date

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Comment: So what happens? Nothing, an error, something unexpedted? Please _edit the question_ and add error message or a description about what happens.

Comment: What makes you believe `Get-ChildItem` would work with URLs?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` only works for "drives" and you have no web drive for it to work with. instead, use the web cmdlets. [*grin*] take a look at these ... `Get-Help *web*` & `Get-Help *rest*` for some ideas. otherwise, do a web search for `powershell website download`.

Answer (score -1):

I think, that you cannot use foreach for your $RemotePath, since it's only string and it requires array. Try to change your first line to:

`$RemotePath = @("http://www.automo.ru/prices.php?uid=0d85f09deeabc9f7473512ee368ed321&opt=Acura&type=csv","http://www.automo.ru/prices.php?uid=0d85f09deeabc9f7473512ee368ed456&opt=Acura&type=csv")`

(don't forget to add both paths to the quotation marks separately)

And then, I'm not sure, if Get-ChildItem can read files somewhere on remote websites.

Comment: Didn't you forget to put it all to brackets?
This sets only basic string $Foo = "abc,abc"
This sets array with two rows and one column $Foo = @("abc", "abc")

Comment: How i said, Get-ChildItem can search only in your drives and not on remote websites over http. Second thing: You have condition "if LastWriteTime -gt ($CurrDate + one more day)". How can any files have lastwritten time bigger, than current day? It would have to be two days in future, to meet this condition.
I would recommend you to download it everytime. Just schedule your script to download it every night and you don't have to deal with these things around. Is it possible in your case?

Comment: $url = "http://www.automo.com/prices.php?uid=0d85f09deeabc9f7473512ee368ed321&opt=Acura&type=csv"
$output = "c:\download\price.csv"
$start_time = Get-Date

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"